Algorithm to populate missing cross-edges in a network graph
I have a network graph with:

$N$ nodes,
$N-1$ edges,
every node has at least one edge (so the network is connected and there are no isolated nodes)

Examples are (this question has nothing to do with computer networks these were just readily available images):


Ultimately I want to complete the network so that there are a total of $N(N-1)/2$ edges, and every node is connected to every other node.
The rules of constructing an edge is to identify a 3-node sub-graph connecting the 3 nodes with two edges and create the third edge using some mathematical function of the values associated with the identified two edges.
Then repeat the search for another 3-node sub graph and populate until there are no more and all edges have been calculated.
(The resultant values are all fully consistent, i.e. the values associated with the edges are not path dependent)
The algorithm I am currently employing is:

identify the node with most outgoing edges.
identify those connected nodes.
for any pair without an existing edge, create one.
repeat until all edges created.

Is this optimal? Is there a name for this or an alternate to use?

I assume that after you pick a node you cross it off the list? otherwise you'll keep picking the same node.
